# Why do British people say Van Gough different than American people?

Tags: pronunciation

Americans say Van Go but British say it Van Goff

Comment: The problem is that English speakers cannot pronounce van Gogh's name the way the Dutch say it (it sounds a little bit like a cough) so we have to mispronounce it. And Americans mispronounce it differently from the British.

Comment: It seems amazing to me that all British pronounce it the same.  Or all Americans.

Comment: Because both are wrong. The correct pronouciation uses a gutteral "g" sound most similar to the "ch" in the Scottish pronounciation of "loch".

Comment: @Brad: If I understand correctly, the correct pronunciation uses two different gutteral *g* sounds.

Comment: @PeterShor many Dutch speakers will devoice both g sounds -- fricative voicing is quite weak -- but phonemically you are correct.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because pronunciation of proper nouns is largely idiosyncratic/a matter of preference, and variable, and not really suitable as an ELU topic.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The British tend to Anglicize many foreign words and phrases. I remember snickering in Junior High School when a substitute teacher said we would spend the hour discussing "Don Kwiksote." In the event, he was actually quite knowledgable and, though not British, preferred the Anglicized pronunciation.

Comment: In this case, the British anglicization is quite a bit closer to the original than the American anglicization. The best anglicization might be *Hoff*, but even that is pretty far from the correct [ɣɔx] (which starts and ends with consonants unpronounceable by English speakers).

Comment: @PeterShor - not arguing with your comment, but is it really true that the consonants *can't* be pronounced by English speakers? Or is it just that they are unfamiliar with it? Pronouncing "l'chaim" correctly, for example, took only a minute of practice to get right, while the /yː/ sound is really difficult for an English speaker who hasn't spoken French a *lot* or from a young age.

Comment: @medica: They can be pronounced by English speakers, but it takes some practice and somebody to explain how to do it. I don't think an English speaker who's not familiar with any foreign languages is going to get it right by just hearing it.

Comment: At least Brits _spell_ 'Paris' the way it's meant to be spelled. Even those who live in Londres. But Long Live la Différence.